# stm32 to arduino serial communication

Tags: types, arduino, stm32, uart

I am sending my adc values to an arduino board via UART.

```
sprintf(data,"\f ADC1= %d ADC2= %d \r\n",adcData[0],adcData[1]);//calisiyor
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2,(uint8_t*)data,strlen(data),1000); //calisiyor
HAL_Delay(500);
```

and my outputs as like this in Tera Term screen;

[image]

my arduino while loop as follow;

```
incomingByte = Serial.read(); // read the incoming byte:
String myString = String(incomingByte);
Serial.print(" I received:");
Serial.println(myString);
```

And the outputs does not like my adc values :)

[image]

What should ı do to see my values as ı sent.

Comment: You are sending the data as strings, i.e. a sequence of bytes. Then receiving them byte at a time, and printing the ASCII code for each byte individually. Your code works fine, `32` is ASCII for a space character, for example.

Comment: Thank you, what should ı do to able to read these values as ı sent, ı could not convert them a string.

Comment: I don't know enough about Arduino to advise, but I think you are close. Hope someone else can comment / answer.

Comment: You are sending a string as "ADC1=xxxx ADC2=yyyy", so it would be easier that you read the incoming as a string instead of byte-by-byte with `String incomingStr = Serial.readStringUntil('\n'); Serial.println(incomingStr);`.

Answer (score 1):

To see your values you sent, you should relay the data as it is sent.

```cpp
int incomingByte = Serial.read(); // read the incoming byte:
if (incomingByte >= 0) { // if there is some input
  Serial.write(incomingByte); // print what is received
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this code, ıt worked as ı want.